# how to make a query to get the last rows matching a list, with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

let's imagine a simple table:

```
name varchar,
ts timestamp,
val int,
UNIQUE (name, ts)
```

I have data pushed to the database as a batch. Every row in that batch has the same timestamp.

I would like to do a query where for a list of names I would get all the rows from the last batch.

For example, if I have:

```
ts           name     val
2020-01-01   joe      3
2020-01-01   eric     5
2020-01-01   amelia   9
2020-01-01   marcel   2
2020-01-01   erika    3
2020-01-02   joe      6
2020-01-02   amelia   8
2020-01-02   marcel   9
2020-01-02   erika    5
```

I would like to be able to pass to the query: [joe, eric, amelia] and only get data from the latest batch (2020-01-02).

The output should be:

```
ts           name     val
2020-01-02   joe      6
2020-01-02   amelia   8
```

So I was thinking about doing a query to know what's the latest timestamp and then do a query requiring that timestamp. Is there a way to do it in a single query?
Also, how can I pass a list of names in this scenario? (I'm a beginner at SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **table** with your table's name:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ts = (SELECT max(ts) FROM table)
```

If you want only certain names add:

```
AND name IN ('joe', 'amelia')
```

Please note: in a transaction gives you the function [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html) always the same value, regardless of how long the transaction is running.

Comment: this works, thanks; so, if I understand well, the now() is evaluated once within a transaction? that's definitely helpful to know.

Comment: Exactly. I'll add a link to the documentation